# Correct way to destroy a slider instance in willDestroyElement callback

Tags: jquery, ember.js

Within an Ember component I am instantiating a slider ( https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider ) and trying to clean it up when then component is destroyed. My setup and tear down functions are:

```
didInsertElement: function() {
  let component = this;
  let elem = component.$().find('.slider')[0];

  let slider = Ember.$(elem).slider({
    ticks: [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100],
    ticks_labels: ['0','20','40','60','80','100'],
    ticks_snap_bounds: 5,
    range: true
  });
  let min = parseInt(component.get('min')),
      max = parseInt(component.get('max'));

  slider.slider('setValue', [ min, max ], true, false);

  slider.on('change', function(evt) {
    component.set('last', evt.value.newValue);
    Ember.run.debounce(component, component.sendScores, 200);
  });

  component.set('slider', slider);
},

willDestroyElement: function() {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(this.get('slider'));
  this.get('slider').destroy();
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting a `Uncaught TypeError: this.get(...).destroy is not a function` exception tear down.

The specific question: what am I doing wrong here so the `destroy()` method is unavailable.

The general question is: should I be storing a "handle" to my slider instance as an Ember property and retrieving it like this or is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a mis-use of the slider library. The correct way to destroy an instance of that library is:

```
willDestroyElement: function() {
  this.get('slider').slider('destroy');
  # NOT: this.get('slider').destroy();
}
```

Comment: Please accept your own question, so others know that this was resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, but you can't accept your own answer for 2 days.